# I need help using the library.add_album feature of pylast (python last.fm api wrapper)

Tags: python, api, last.fm

I am trying to access the library class of pylast, but must be doing something wrong. I can get most other features to work.  The following is a code example which just takes the standard working example and adds what I believe to be the correct way of adding an album to my last.fm library:

```
import pylast

# You have to have your own unique two values for API_KEY and API_SECRET
# Obtain yours from http://www.last.fm/api/account for Last.fm
API_KEY = "80a1c765efb52869575821c03d93a30e" # this is a sample key
API_SECRET = "2ba567f5b0d74c6cc6a8d07ef2cbc2d"

# In order to perform a write operation you need to authenticate yourself
username = "astroid0"
password_hash = pylast.md5("xxx")

network = pylast.LastFMNetwork(api_key = API_KEY, api_secret = 
    API_SECRET, username = username, password_hash = password_hash)

# now you can use that object every where
artist = network.get_artist("System of a Down")
artist.shout("<3")


track = network.get_track("Iron Maiden", "The Nomad")
track.love()
track.add_tags(("awesome", "favorite"))

## This is the area causing trouble
library1 = pylast.Library(user = "astroid0", network = "LastFM")
album1 = network.get_album("The Rolling Stones", "Sticky Fingers")
library1.add_album(album1)
```

ss the library class of pylast, but must be doing something wrong. I can get most other features to work.  The following is a code example which just takes the standard working example and adds what I believe to be the correct way of adding an album to my last.fm library:

```
 library1 = pylast.Library(user = "astroid0", network = "LastFM")
 album1 = network.get_album("The Rolling Stones", "Sticky Fingers")
 library1.add_album(album1)
```

I am new to python, so I am sorry if this is obvious, I have just been stuck for days now, and decided to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in pylast.

Line 1957 (from trunk) should be:

```
params["artist"] = album.get_artist().get_name()
```

instead of:

```
params["artist"] = album.get_artist.get_name()
```

You can report the issue to the author [here](http://code.google.com/p/pylast/issues/list).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the one function of pylast I have been interested in, and it has driven me crazy! A thousand thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by miles82](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5542465/724176) shows the bug and it's been [reported to pylast](https://code.google.com/p/pylast/issues/detail?id=66&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Reporter%20Summary).

Unfortunately there's been no updates in a few years so I've fixed this in my [fork of pylast](https://github.com/hugovk/pylast).